# What advantages does the Water Park have over an Entertainment district?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

The new *Rise and Fall* expansion for Civilization 6 adds a new district, the Water Park. It provides amenities like the Entertainment district but can only be built on coastal tiles. Given that a city cannot build both, why would I choose a Water Park which costs more to build and comes late in the game?

Answer (score 6):

You will not unlock the Water Park until later in the game, consequently the Water Park cost more production to build. However all things aside the major difference is a fully upgraded Water Park will provide the same amount of amenities except instead it will be 9 tile radius instead of 6 however the Water Park has to be built in the water on a coastal tile. As an added bonus you get a slight tourism and science boost with the Water Park as well.

You are better off with the Water Park but only for cities with coastal tiles and assuming you haven't built an Entertainment District earlier in the game!

Comment: It's great for solving late-game happiness problems where you've run out of land to build.

Comment: As far as I can tell, entertainment district and water park amenity boosts stack, so I'd definitely build both.

Answer (score 3):

So far the Water Park has been very handy for coastal cities and small islands that do not have a lot of land squares, as if there's only a couple of land squares for food and production at least you can build a harbor and water park.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to alternate towns picking Entertainment Complex and Water Park in a way we get bonuses from both Districts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).